# Linking to another html document when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Am trying to redirect to another html document when a button is clicked. This is my js code:

```
$('#getTextBoxValue').on("click", function(){
var value = $("#textbox1").val();
});

$('#getTextBoxValue').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'view.html';
    return false;
});
```

And this is my html code:

```
<form class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:500px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter single quote-surrounded link" type="textbox" id="textbox1"></input>
              <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id= "getTextBoxValue">Submit</button></span>
            </div>
          </form>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/viewer.js"></script>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button though, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have two `$$` in front of the function.. is that throwing an error?

Comment: what is wrong with an ordinary `<a href='...'>`?

Comment: The console is your friend.

Comment: `<\script>` instead of `</script>` concerns me

Comment: LOL at the comments so far... Maybe just add an action to the form? Are you trying to pass the contents of the input to the next page as well? If so, just set the form attribute action='view.html'... And change the button to input; type is already submit.

Comment: @PaulRoub whoops am very used to writing in latex and sometimes use \ instead of / for that reason.

Comment: @tymeJV no errors, just nothing is happening

Comment: @mark.hch yes trying to pass the content of the input to the next page (the idea is to have the user enter a link and then open the paper using pdf.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any javascript to do this just set your action of your form as below:

```
<form class="col-lg-12" action="view.html">
            <div class="input-group" style="width:500px;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;">
            <input class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter single quote-surrounded link" type="textbox" id="textbox1"></input>
              <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" id= "getTextBoxValue">Submit</button></span>
            </div>
          </form>
<script src="js/script.js"><\script>
<script src="js/viewer.js"><\script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that [doesn't need jQuery, only vanilla javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/ztpsfmb7/):

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
        function goToPage() {
            document.location = 'view.html';
        }
        Button.addEventListener('click', goToPage);
    </script>
    …
    <button id="Button">Go</button>
```

- You create your `button` element and give it a unique `id` attribute (it can be any element).
- Then you add a *click* `EventListener` to it, that executes the specified *function* `goToPage`.
- The `goToPage` function changes the document's `location` to navigate to it.

And one that [doesn't even need javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/arielnmz/ha8qcjag/):

```
    <form action="view.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
```

- You only create an `input` element of type `submit`.
- Then you just put it into a `form` element with your document's URL as the `action`.

The advantages of the first approach is that you can make *almost* any element you want clickable, there are only a few exceptions. The advantage of the second one is that you only use pure HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this html:

```
<input type='button' id='unique_identifier'>
```

And this little javascript snippet (using jQuery):

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
$('#unique_identifier').on('click', function () {
  window.location.replace('view.html');
});

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
$('#unique_identifier').on('click', function () {
  window.location.href = 'view.html';
});
```

[Thanks to Ryan McGeary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/1865613)